# UK passport expiring

Tags: passports, uk-citizens

I can not find the answer anywhere. I will leave the USA in August 2019 after working here for 2 years. My British passport expires in January 2020. That's 4 months until it expires. As a citizen returning home, is this allowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As a citizen returning home, is this allowed?

Yes.  Many countries have passport validity restrictions for foreigners entering the country, to ensure that the passport won't expire during the visit.  These restrictions do not generally apply to a country's own nationals.  In general, on exit, the only requirement is that your passport be valid.

In particular, the US does not require any minimum validity when you leave the US.  They don't directly check passports of departing travelers; they rely on airlines to pass information about those travelers to the government.  Accordingly, there is not much mention of passport validity requirements on departure in the laws or regulations.

The UK will even [allow you to enter the UK with an expired UK passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/43884/19400), so, on that end of your trip, a passport with four months' remaining validity is certainly fine.