# UK citizen on school trip with US passport?

Tags: usa, france, uk-citizens, minors

My daughter is 14 and is due to go on a school trip to France in 13 days rom the UK. We just realised that her UK passport is expired. But she also has a valid US passport. Can she use this? And if not, will we be able to get her a UK replacement passport in time?

Comment: You can get  UK passport in less than 13 days. There are 3 options listed on the Gov website: https://www.gov.uk/get-a-passport-urgently

Answer (score 6):

I cannot think of a reason why a US citizen would be unable to travel to France from the UK with a school group using her US passport, even if she is also a British citizen.

To get back into the UK, however, she should bring some evidence of her British citizenship.  The expired passport should suffice.  See, for example

- [Can I enter the UK on my expired British passport if I have a valid South African passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/43877/19400)
- [Do I have to enter the UK on my UK passport?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/7043/19400)